# checksum for UTF-8 string

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8

Below is the checksum description. 
The checksum is four ASCII character digits representing the binary sum of the characters including the
first character of the transmission and up to and including the checksum field identifier characters.
To calculate the checksum add each character as an unsigned binary number, take the lower 16 bits of the
total and perform a 2's complement. The checksum field is the result represented by four hex digits.
To verify the correct checksum on received data, simply add all the hex values including the checksum. It
should equal zero.

this is the implementation for ASCII string, but my input string is UTF-8 now.
anyone give some idea to revise the implementation for UTF-8 encoding. Thanks very much.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SIP2
{
    //  Adapted from VB.NET from the Library Tech Guy blog
    //  http://librarytechguy.blogspot.com/2009/11/sip2-checksum_13.html

    public class CheckSum
    {
        public static string ApplyChecksum(string strMsg)
        {
            int intCtr;
            char[] chrArray;
            int intAscSum;
            bool blnCarryBit;
            string strBinVal = String.Empty;
            string strInvBinVal;
            string strNewBinVal = String.Empty;

            // Transfer SIP message to a a character array.Loop through each character of the array,
            // converting the character to an ASCII value and adding the value to a running total.

            intAscSum = 0;
            chrArray = strMsg.ToCharArray();

            for (intCtr = 0; intCtr <= chrArray.Length - 1; intCtr++)
            {
                intAscSum = intAscSum + (chrArray[intCtr]);
            }

            // Next, convert ASCII sum to a binary digit by: 
            // 1) taking the remainder of the ASCII sum divided by 2 
            // 2) Repeat until sum reaches 0 
            // 3) Pad to 16 digits with leading zeroes 

            do
            {
                strBinVal = (intAscSum % 2).ToString() + strBinVal;
                intAscSum = intAscSum / 2;
            } while (intAscSum > 0);

            strBinVal = strBinVal.PadLeft(16, '0');

            // Next, invert all bits in binary number. 
            chrArray = strBinVal.ToCharArray();
            strInvBinVal = "";

            for (intCtr = 0; intCtr <= chrArray.Length - 1; intCtr++)
            {
                if (chrArray[intCtr] == '0') { strInvBinVal = strInvBinVal + '1'; }
                else { strInvBinVal = strInvBinVal + '0'; }
            }


            // Next, add 1 to the inverted binary digit. Loop from least significant digit (rightmost) to most (leftmost); 
            // if digit is 1, flip to 0 and retain carry bit to next significant digit. 

            blnCarryBit = true;
            chrArray = strInvBinVal.ToCharArray();

            for (intCtr = chrArray.Length - 1; intCtr >= 0; intCtr--)
            {
                if (blnCarryBit == true)
                {
                    if (chrArray[intCtr] == '0')
                    {
                        chrArray[intCtr] = '1';
                        blnCarryBit = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chrArray[intCtr] = '0';
                        blnCarryBit = true;
                    }
                }
                strNewBinVal = chrArray[intCtr] + strNewBinVal;
            }

            // Finally, convert binary digit to hex value, append to original SIP message. 
            return strMsg + (Convert.ToInt16(strNewBinVal, 2)).ToString("X");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should post the code here instead of a link to it.

Comment: thank you. I have posted it.

Comment: What _specifically_ are you having trouble with? The checksum for ASCII is essentially a checksum of bytes. So you could just take the UTF8 bytes and checksum those instead. Why are you computing a checksum? Is there some specific checksum implementation you're required to comply with? Is this some sort of academic exercise?

Comment: How did you verify the checksum in the implementation for ASCII strings? What happens if you compute the checksum for a UTF-8 string and try to verify the checksum in the same way?

Comment: The checksum is for SIP2 message error detection at application level. SIP2 is a communication protocol  between library automation system and automation device. The checksum algorithm already described in my question. the protocol communication use TCP Socket.

Comment: http://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/78960O/standard-protocol-definitions-document.pdf

Comment: Thank you very much. Peter and Poosh.

Comment: it is not exercise. it is for work, I am new in the programming. Peter is right, just add up UTF8 bytes. thank you very much.

Comment: Solutions/answers never belong in a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the code

```
for (intCtr = 0; intCtr <= chrArray.Length - 1; intCtr++)
{
    intAscSum = intAscSum + (chrArray[intCtr]); 
}
```

`chrArray[intCtr]` is input ASCII String to ouput the ASCII code in decimal, for example "A" is 65. ASCII encoding only uses 1 byte. UTF-8 uses one byte or more than one byte to represent the UTF-8 char. I think `chrArray[intCtr]` is designed for ASCII - thus the input of UTF-8 (more than one byte) is not reasonable.

With

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
{
    intAscSum = intAscSum + bytes[i];
}
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strMsg);
```

Add up all the bytes, because one UTF8 char can be more than one byte.